# Why terraform is unable to compute a local variable correctly in the following trivial scenario?

Tags: terraform

Given is the following configuration (main.tf):

```
locals {
    locations = toset(["a", "b"])
}

resource "local_file" "instance" {
    for_each = local.locations

    content  = each.value
    filename = "${path.module}/${each.value}.txt"
}

output "primary_filename" {
    value = local_file.instance["a"].filename
}
```

And it seems to work fine:

```
C:\work\test> dir


    Directory: C:\work\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        4/15/2020  11:47 PM            280 main.tf


C:\work\test> terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...
- Downloading plugin for provider "local" (hashicorp/local) 1.4.0...

...
C:\work\test> terraform apply -auto-approve
local_file.instance["b"]: Creating...
local_file.instance["a"]: Creating...
local_file.instance["a"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8]
local_file.instance["b"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=e9d71f5ee7c92d6dc9e92ffdad17b8bd49418f98]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

primary_filename = ./a.txt
C:\work\test>
```

Now I delete the file `a.txt` and rerun:

```
C:\work\test> del .\a.txt
C:\work\test> terraform apply -auto-approve
local_file.instance["a"]: Refreshing state... [id=86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8]
local_file.instance["b"]: Refreshing state... [id=e9d71f5ee7c92d6dc9e92ffdad17b8bd49418f98]

Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 13, in output "primary_filename":
  13:     value = local_file.instance["a"].filename
    |----------------
    | local_file.instance is object with 1 attribute "b"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

It can be fixed by using the `try` function:

```
    value = try(local_file.instance["a"].filename, "")
```

Which does make it work:

```
C:\work\test> terraform apply -auto-approve
local_file.instance["b"]: Refreshing state... [id=e9d71f5ee7c92d6dc9e92ffdad17b8bd49418f98]
local_file.instance["a"]: Refreshing state... [id=86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8]
local_file.instance["a"]: Creating...
local_file.instance["a"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

primary_filename = ./a.txt
C:\work\test>
```

Now I know we are not supposed to delete resources outside of terraform, but things happen and my expectation is that terraform handles it gracefully. And it does, except for this local variable behavior.

I do not like using the `try` function, because it would hide a real problem. Ideally, it should behave like `try` during the plan phase and without `try` during the apply phase.

Anyway, I have a feeling I am missing something important here, like I am not using the local variables correctly or something else. So, what am I missing?

Comment: This is a little hard to follow as is. Could you try to produce an [mcve] so that it's possible to run it? It doesn't look like you need the Azure provider at all here and should be able to produce a very minimal example using just variables and locals that people can easily run to see how to solve your error.

Comment: Yeah, I know I was lazy. I will try to come up with a minimal reproduction, though I do not know how can I do it without the actual cloud resources. The problem happens when a cloud resource managed by TF is destroyed outside of TF. How do I simulate it without the cloud?

Comment: I have completely reworked the question with a minimal reproduction that does not depend on any cloud.